# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call ( Python )

Tags: python, opencv

I have error in this line of my code, I need help pls!!!

```
predict_func(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[i])
```

It shows this error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: This error is correct. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: What are you trying to assign the result of `cv2.boundingRect(cnts[i])` to? How do you want to access the result? What's the purpose of trying to assign it to `predict_func(x, y, w, h)`? Are you maybe trying to change the return value of `predict_func` for future calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a function to a function. Functions do not have a static value as you are trying to assign, and therefore you cannot simply assign another function to it. Maybe you want to assign each to a variable like this:

```
my_var1 = predict_func(x, y, w, h)
my_var2 = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[i])
```

Or maybe you want this:

```
def predict_func(x, y, w, h):
    return cv2.boundingRect(cnts[i])
```

But this would be strange, as none of `predict_func`s parameters are used, so if you would provide clarification on what you are trying to do, we may be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight forward - you are trying to assign the returned value of a function to **another function.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def predict_func(x, y, w, h):
    return cv2.boundingRect(cnts[i])
```